# failed to load jvm dll C:\Program Files\JetBrains\Intelij IDEA Community EDItio 2018.2.2\jre64\\bin\server\jvm.dll

Tags: intellij-idea

I have such a problem.

> failed to load jvm dll C:\Program Files\JetBrains\Intelij IDEA Community EDItio 2018.2.2\jre64\bin\server\jvm.dll

[image]

Comment: Help me please!

Comment: I looked at other topics but I can not solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have jvm.dll on that path?

Comment: Yes I have path

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin

Comment: Problem in the JAVA_HOME because his 

did not exist at all

Comment: I aded his ////